# Xquery nodes value

Tags: sql-server, xquery

I need to get the value of AccountName in my table

```
<rows>
  <Row xmlns="http://adcenter.microsoft.com/advertiser/reporting/v5/XMLSchema">
    <AccountName value="MA_Yellowpages - AdStore" />
  </Row>
</rows>
```

I am using below thing -

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://adcenter.microsoft.com/advertiser/reporting/v5/XMLSchema' AS ns)
select
temp.query('AccountName[1]').value('@value','varchar(1000)') AS AC
from  yp.dbo.Audit_ApiCallRawXml CROSS APPLY
      RawXML.nodes('/rows/ns:Row') lg(temp)
```

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there - but you need to also make sure to use the XML namespace on the `AccountName` element that is inside the `<Row>` node. Additionally, I would write your query like this:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://adcenter.microsoft.com/advertiser/reporting/v5/XMLSchema' AS ns)
SELECT
   temp.value('(ns:AccountName/@value)[1]', 'varchar(1000)') AS AC
FROM
   yp.dbo.Audit_ApiCallRawXml 
CROSS APPLY
   RawXML.nodes('/rows/ns:Row') lg(temp)
```

This should hopefully work then.